# How do we keep posts created with Contentlayer dynamic for new posts on vercel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

my problem is that on the page I created with the contentlayer, I show my blog posts from github via vercel, but when I post a new post to github, I cannot see my post because it is not built. What can I do on the site I coded with Nextjs13?

Contentlayer Config file is down

```
import { defineDocumentType, makeSource } from 'contentlayer/source-files'

export const Post = defineDocumentType(() => ({
  name: 'Post',
  filePathPattern: `**/*.md`,
  fields: {
    title: {
      type: 'string',
      description: 'The title of the post',
      required: true,
    },
    subtitle:{
      type:'string',
      description:'The subtitle of the post',
      required:true,
    },
    date: {
      type: 'date',
      description: 'The date of the post',
      required: true,
    },
    keywords:{
      type:'string',
      description:'Meta Etiketleri',
      required:true
    },
    description:{
      type:'string',
      description:'Meta Etiketleri',
      required:true
    }

  },
  computedFields: {
    url: {
      type: 'string',
      resolve: (post) => `Blog/Yazilar/${post._raw.flattenedPath}`,
    },
  },
}))

export default makeSource({
  contentDirPath: 'posts',
  documentTypes: [Post],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your blog page setup correctly to use all built blog posts, all you need to do is build your contentlayer mdx files before you build your next application. In your package.json scripts, add the following build script:

```json
"build": "contentlayer build && next build"
```

This way, contentlayer first builds your mdx files. Then next can build the rest of the application using the generated files.

Also, it's recommended to add `.contentlayer` to your gitignore since all files in there are automatically generated for each build